# How to make one square spawn randomly once?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
boolean keyPressed = true;
boolean mousePressed = true;
PShape circle;
int  x;
int  y;

void setup() {
    background(0);
    fullScreen(1);
    frameRate(144);
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    circle = createShape(ELLIPSE, 0, 0, 50, 50);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);

    if (mousePressed == true) {
        noCursor();
    }

    if (keyPressed == true && key == 'w') {
        x = int(random(width));
        y = int(random(height));
        rect(x, y, 40, 40);
        fill(255, 0, 255);
    }

    if (key == 's') {
        background(0);
    }

    translate(mouseX, mouseY);
    shape(circle);
}
```

Currently when pressing `W` the shape appears rapidly. I would like to have it where the shape spawns once, then when the background is cleared and `W` is pressed again the shape is located somewhere else.

Comment: is this some kind of Processing code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, consider adding tags to your question to help identify your code. As it stands, the library you are using has to be implied, because nowhere in your code did you specify that it is Processing code (which I'm assuming it is). For more information on how to ask a good question, check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).